# How to get the file name after getting a blob using storage.get method in google cloud storage using java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to get the file name of a Blob that I get after calling google storage get method like this

```
Blob blob = storage.get(bucketName, path);
```

this returns me a Blob an inside that blob is a an attribute called "name" but that is the whole path of the file, I just want to get the file name, without needing to slice the string.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not have directories. The full pathname of the object is the name. The `/` character is not a directory separator, it is just a character in the object name.

Comment: As @JohnHanley said, you need to use a substring and lastIndexOf("/").